# last digit of $n^5$ and $n$ is the same digit

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The last digit of $n^5-n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85701/the-last-digit-of-n5-n)
>   [Why is the last digit of $n^5$ equal to the last digit of $n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184609/why-is-the-last-digit-of-n5-equal-to-the-last-digit-of-n)

Basically, this is the same question as
[Why is the last digit of $n^5$ equal to the last digit of $n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184609/why-is-the-last-digit-of-n5-equal-to-the-last-digit-of-n)

What I want to prove is

$n^5 ≡ n$  mod 10

Since I'm studying Euler's Phi Function, I know that the proof of this is related to it. So I'm looking to prove this using the Phi function. A comment on the original question suggests $φ(10)=4$ but I don't see how I can use this. Anyone can point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: This is answered in the following answer to the linked question: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/184623/19379

Comment: If it's the same question, why ask again?

Comment: I think a relation holds: $n^{4k + 1} \equiv n \pmod{10}$ for any positive integer $k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Euler's theorem states that if $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then

$$a^{\varphi(n)} ≡ 1 \mbox{ mod } n$$

Multiply by $a$ on both sides,

$$a^{\varphi(n) + 1} ≡ a \mbox{ mod } n$$

Now set $n = 10$. Does this help?

Comment: Don't $a$ and $n$ have to be coprime ?

Comment: Ahh yes that was very clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

When $n\equiv 0,1\pmod 2\implies n^5\equiv 0,1\pmod 2\implies n^5\equiv n\pmod {2}$

Also, $n^5\equiv n\pmod {5}$ (By Fermat's little theorem)

By Chinese remainder theorem,

These both $\implies n^5-n\equiv 0\pmod {10}\implies n^5\equiv n\pmod {10}$

Comment: Can you please add detaild on your third paragraph ? Why is the condition about $a$ and $n$ being coprime can be remived ?

Comment: That was not true in general; i removed it.